# Create Custom Product Collection in Magento with price or other attributes

Tags: magento

I am new to magento and my question is
How to create custom product collection for an e.g I want all those products which have  price minimum $200 and max $300

any help would be appreciated..... 
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToSort('price', 'desc')
->addFieldToFilter('price',array('from'=>'200','to'=>'300'))->load();
```

Once you got collection using this you can play with this as you need.

try this too

```
->addFieldToFilter('price',array('gt' => '200', 'lt' => '300'))
```

Comment: not able to vote up because I have not enough reputation, if you don't mind then you can vote up my question so that I can earn reputation then I will do that.... thanks @Rohan

Answer (score 0):

Include the `product` with **price minimum $200 and maximum $300** in one new `category` and display the product belonging to that `category` only.

Comment: Thanks for replay but I have to add product two time once in main category and secondly on suggested by you this is not desire solution....

Answer (score -1):

```
$variable = Mage::getModel('folder/model_name')->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
   ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array(
    'from' => '200',
    'to' => '300'
    ))
    ->load();
```